# Fedora 16 system unresponsive - why?

Tags: fedora

The display was still showing things but the keyboard and mouse weren't working, ssh wasn't working and neither was ftp.  After a power cycle the system came back fine.  What would have caused this?

The system was up for about 2 weeks (and last used about 8 hours before this occurred.)

*** Which logfiles should I be looking at?

Comment: ...and the logfiles said...?

Comment: My guess is solar flares btw.

Comment: *gremlins*...they come out this time of year.

Answer (score 1):

For that kind of situations, most likely are

- Overheating
- Bad RAM
- Bad motherboard
- Bad powersupply
- Very buggy display drivers

Comment: You forgot hard disk going bad. The logs should indicate that. I find that more likely than bad power supply or motherboard, or even display drivers if it had been stable for a long period of time.

Answer (score 0):

It cud be *a lot* of fings. Rly u need 2 dig through sum log files, or setup monitoring incase it happen's again.

Comment: Those dam Alots, [they get everywhere](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html)

Comment: is now fixed !   ........

Comment: HAHAHA the English pedant in me hates you.

Comment: I don't even...what?